# ACF Pro make URL Linked in Custom Template

Tags: theme-development, urls, advanced-custom-fields

I am new to ACF and Custom Post Types and novice at best with PHP & Coding.

I need help to make `the_field` linked on my front end display.  I also want to show the link as the link text.

```
<?php
if( get_field('svcta_contact_information_group_svcta_contact_website')) {
echo '<div class="svcta-contact-website" id="svcta-id-contact-website">';
echo '<strong>Contact Website:</strong> ';
the_field('svcta_contact_information_group_svcta_contact_website');
echo '</div>';
}
?>
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Is `svcta_contact_information_group_svcta_contact_website` a URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You echo value of the field, so you get what you do ;) There is no way to make ACF print it your way. You have to wrap it yourself.

Here's a code that would do exactly that:

```
<?php if ( get_field('svcta_contact_information_group_svcta_contact_website') ) : ?>
    <div class="svcta-contact-website" id="svcta-id-contact-website">
        <strong>Contact Website:</strong>
        <a href="<?php echo esc_attr( get_field('svcta_contact_information_group_svcta_contact_website') ); ?>">Link Caption</a>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

change this line:

`the_field('svcta_contact_information_group_svcta_contact_website');`

with this:

`echo '<a href=" . esc_attr( get_field('svcta_contact_information_group_svcta_contact_website') ) . ">Link Text</a>';`

Comment: Without any escaping? Really?

Comment: Edited to add it in.

Comment: it won’t work. the_field already prints the value - it doesn’t return anything. So you can’t use it in string concatenation and there is no point in wrapping it with esc_attr... You should use get_field instead.